# Как сохранить положение скроллинга RecycleView при переключении фрагментов?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Задача такая: есть несколько фрагментов, в каждом - `RecycleView`.

Нужно, чтобы при переключении фрагментов в каждом фрагменте сохранялась позиция скроллинга списка, чтобы не с начала.

Как это правильнее архитектурно реализовать, т.е. либо все фрагменты одновременно хранить в разных контейнерах, либо как-то сохранять их состояние и затем `replace` в один контейнер ... В общем, не совсем понятно..

Фрагменты переключаются через `BottomNavigationView`.

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняете в `onPause()`, восстанавливаете в `onResume()`

Сохранение

```
lastFirstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView
.getLayoutManager())
.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Восстановление

```
((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager())
.scrollToPositionWithOffset(lastFirstVisiblePosition,0)
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27954051/9007098)

Comment: Спасибо, но если я правильно понимаю, то в примере сохраняется/восстанавливается позиция первого полностью видимого элемента, а не точной позиции скроллинга?